# How to increasing width of relative div automatically in case of overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with `position:absolute`. Inside of that div I want to add some small divs programmatically. So I adjusted the `overflow-x:scroll`.

Now I want to have a div at the top of those small divs (the `antiquewhite` colored div in the picture). I adjusted its 'width:100%'. But as soon as I scroll to right to see the hidden contents I see that the div can not adjust its width to 100%.

This problem is exist also when I use the magnifier of the browser and change the view size.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code. The HTML part:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='convas'>
  <div class='top'>

  </div>
  <div class='bottom' id='parent'>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS part:

```
.container{
  margin:10px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.convas{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
  width:90%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  }
  .top{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
  }
  .bottom{
  }
 .cell{
      border: 1px dashed #050505;                 
      width:20px;
      height:80px;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:100px;  
  }
```

And the JavaScript part:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
console.log(parent);
for(var i=1; i<50;i++){
    let elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.className = 'cell';
    elem.style.left = i* 20 +'px';
  elem.innerText = i;
  parent.appendChild(elem);
}
```

And here is the sample for running: https://jsfiddle.net/mjza/9nzzwxf4/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code, that will help to see where the problem is.

Comment: I added sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see snippet bellow or jsfiddle here > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nzzwxf4/2/)

so i calculated the sum of the widths of all  the `cells` . and then gave that width to the `.top` div

this calculation is made on window resize. and to make that happen also on page load , i called the `resize()` function on page load.

let me know if it helps

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
console.log(parent);
for(var i=0; i<50;i++){
 let elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.className = 'cell';
 elem.style.left = i* 20 +'px';
  elem.innerText = i;
  parent.appendChild(elem);
}
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $('.convas .cell').each(function() {
        totalWidth += Number($(this).width());
    });
   $('.top').width(totalWidth)   
}).resize();
```

```css
.container{
  margin:10px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.convas{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
  width:90%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  }
  
  .top{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
  }
  .bottom{
  }
 .cell{
      border: 1px dashed #050505;                 
      width:20px;
      height:80px;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:100px;  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
<div class='convas'>
  <div class='top'>

  </div>
  <div class='bottom' id='parent'>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is more or less same as what @Majid did. I don't want to modify the width of top div inside of JS. I want to use CSS width:auto or something similar that when I change the zoom out the page then the top div increase to have 100% width.
Just zoom out to 30% in your browser and see that this problem exist yet.

Comment: @MahdiJaberzadeh you want something that can't be done with CSS

Comment: OK. I thought it is a bug in browsers. Actually when I put width:100% it calculates the width of the visible part of the container. But as I add cells to the inner div, the width of the outer container is increased but the elements that have width:100% are not effected from this increment. Anyway thanks.

Comment: yes . that happens because of the use of `overflow` . that's why...i calculated the width of `.top` depending on how many `cells` you have . that's how my solution works ( both on page load and on resize )

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is that you modify the top div as long as you create the cells inside of the Javascript.

Assume you top div have the id equal to `top`. Then the Javascript has to change like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var top = document.getElementById('top');
for(var i=0; i<50;i++){
  let elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.className = 'cell';
  elem.style.left = i*20 +'px';
  if(top.clientWidth < (i*20+20))
     top.style.width = (i*20 + 20) +'px';
  elem.innerText = i;
  parent.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Dear Majid, actully I thought to this solution also. It is a good solution as soon as user doesn't change the page size. For example if you change the view of your browser to 50% then the empty space appears again. I need some technique that increase or decrease the width of top div to cover 100% of its parent div's width.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I don't know any method for that. Sorry.